# Silently Upgrade the software without User Access Control

Tags: java, cmd, installshield

What I want to know is, Is there any way out to silently upgrade my software without my client knowing about it. I just want to bypass all the User Access Control and do the upgrade to a higher version.

Comment: We need more context on your application - are you a) distributing a standalone double-click jar b) a zip file with libraries in separate files and a run script or c) a launch4j application?

Comment: If it is a minor upgrade then just a patch upgrade and if major changes are done then  the previous should get uninstalled and should be replaced via the new one ..

Comment: jitterbit-agent-8.7.0.2.exe /s /v/qn   i have this cmd to silently upgrade the application , but it prompts while installing in a non admin account ..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "bypass" UAC; you have to work within its constraints. However Windows Installer does provide one specific escape hatch that might overlap with what you want: [User Account Control (UAC) Patching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372388.aspx). There's a [related question on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/485323) that also references this documentation.

There are a lot of requirements for UAC patching to work correctly, so here's a very high level overview:

- You have to have installed your base package on a new enough operating system and version of Windows Installer
- The base package must include a reference to the certificate that is (will be) used to sign the patch
- This only works for patches, so if you have trouble building patches for your update, you're out of luck

Many people find the actual process quite onerous and choose instead to deliver per-user installations that do not require administrative privileges to install or update.